# Cannot add Scaffold > MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

When I try to add Controller using build-in generator I get following error message:
[image: Error message box on controller generation]

Where "Brand" is a model class and "ApplicationDbContext" is my data context class.
I never encoutered error like this before. It does **not** occur all the time (2 success vs 30-40 attempts without changing single line of code). I was able to create Controller for **same class** minutes ago, but it's really annoying when you try to add something new and try more than 10 times with no results.
Of course, I **could** write my own controller and views, but I really like using included tools.
I have already repaired VS using "Modify" option in "Add or remove". I'm using latest Microsoft Visual Studio Community (MVSC2015 V14.0.25425.01 Update3).
**EDIT:**
Brand.cs:

```
namespace AppBrander.Models  
{  
    public class Brand  
    {  
        public int ID { get; set; }  
        public string Email { get; set; }  
        public string BrandName { get; set; }  
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }  
        public string Description { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

Works in brand new project, fails in old - I guess it's just my VS installation being totally messed up. I should have been guessed, but I just did **second** repair...

Comment: Can you please share your Brand model class?

Comment: @Sanket2 Found error there - I don't know how it passed that 2 times. I will post answer below ^^"

Comment: I thought I found out what is happening, but I was wrong. I'm editing post for more info.

Comment: @Akkaryk: Are you compiling/building your projects before doing Scaffolding when you change the models? This is required in order for the scaffolding engine to recognize the newly added types

Comment: @Tseng I never thought about it... But yes, after first error box I did compile/build (and clean, rebuild, debug - basically everything that came to my head). Right now I work in new project when generating succeded... randomly, without changing anything.