# Entity Framework Core 1.0 not scaffolding Controller and View

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro), using Visual Studio Community 2015 v 14.0.25431.01 Update 3  and MS .NET Framework v 4.6.91586, but get the following error when I attempt to scaffold the controller, as described:

[image: Error]

I have tried all the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374242/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object-in-asp-net-mvc-controller) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869883/cannot-add-scaffold-mvc-controller-with-views-using-entity-framework-in-asp-n), but to no avail. Yes, also tried (re)building the project.

Here is the relevant code from my project.

Student Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SchoolContext:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        }

    }
```

Added the SchoolContext to the services in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And this is my connectionstring in appSetting.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-ContosoUniversity-75b88406-9d10-4237-814a-3f725b9b4e3d;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I've managed to get over the problem of not having a parameterless constructor. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374242/no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object-in-asp-net-mvc-controller), I simply provided the constructors to both the DBContext class  as well as the Model class  as such:

```
public Student() { }
```

Now I'm getting a different error. I guess I need to pose it as a new question. I will, but for what it's worth, this is part of the error log:

```
        Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: Student
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkServices.TryCreateContextUsingAppCode(Type dbContextType, ModelType startupType)
    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) StackTrace:
...
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    There is no entity type Student on DbContext ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject,...
```

Comment: As it turns out, my install of VS 2015 was somehow corrupted. Re-installed and the scaffolding is working perfectly -- if very slowly (compared to Rails).